# Making a help command with paginator and select-menu

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, paginator, discord-buttons

I am using discord_components for help commands. I am trying to create help command like dank memer in python.
 Below is the help command of dank-memer
[image: Help command of Dank-Memer]

**This is my code**

```
@commands.command()
    async def select_and_buttons(self, ctx):
      embed1=discord.Embed(title="no:1")
      embed2=discord.Embed(title="no:2")
      embed3=discord.Embed(title="no:3")
      embed4=discord.Embed(title="no:4")
      embed5=discord.Embed(title="no:5")
      embed6=discord.Embed(title="no:6")
      embed7=discord.Embed(title="no:7")
      embed8=discord.Embed(title="no:8")
      embed9=discord.Embed(title="no:9")
      embed10=discord.Embed(title="no:10")
      pages = [embed1, embed2, embed3, embed4, embed5]
      page0 = [embed1, embed2, embed3, embed4, embed5]
      page1 = [embed6, embed7, embed8, embed9, embed10]
      total_pages=[page0,page1]
      page = 0
      category="Moderation ️"
      components = [
          [
              Select(
                  placeholder="Select something",
                  options=[
                      SelectOption(label='Moderation', value='Moderation', emoji='️',default=True),
                      SelectOption(label='Giveaway', value='Giveaway', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Games', value='Games', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Music', value='Music', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Fun', value='Fun', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Utils', value='Utils', emoji='️',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Tickets', value='Tickets', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Others', value='Others', emoji='✨',default=False)
                      ]
              )
          ],
          [
              Button(emoji="⏮️",label=' ', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='move_to_first',disabled=True),
              Button(emoji="⬅️",label=' ', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='move_to_back',disabled=True),
              Button(emoji="➡️",label=' ', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='move_to_next'),
              Button(emoji="⏭️",label=' ', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='move_to_last')
          ]
      ]

      message = await ctx.send(embed=pages[page], components=components)

      while True:
          try:
              interaction = await self.bot.wait_for(
                  'interaction',
                  check=lambda inter: inter.message.id == message.id,
                  timeout=60
              )
          except asyncio.TimeoutError:
              for row in components:
                  row.disable_components()
              return await message.edit(content='Timed out!', components=components)



          if isinstance(interaction.component, Select):
              components[0][0].default=False
              
              SelectOption.default=True
              pages=page1
              page=0
              try:
                components[1][0].disabled=True
                components[1][1].disabled=True
                print("check")
              except:
                pass  
              await interaction.edit_origin(embed=pages[page], components = components)  


          # else:
          if isinstance(interaction.component, Button):
              if interaction.custom_id=="move_to_first": 
                if(page==len(pages)-1):
                  components[1][2].disabled = False
                  components[1][3].disabled = False
                page=0  
                components[1][1].disabled = True
                components[1][0].disabled = True

              if interaction.custom_id=="move_to_last": 
                if(page==0):
                  components[1][1].disabled = False
                  components[1][0].disabled = False
                page=len(pages)-1 
                components[1][2].disabled = True
                components[1][3].disabled = True  

              if interaction.custom_id == 'move_to_back':
                if page == len(pages)-1:
                    components[1][2].disabled = False
                    components[1][3].disabled = False
                page -= 1
                if page == 0:
                    components[1][1].disabled = True
                    components[1][0].disabled = True
              elif interaction.custom_id == 'move_to_next':
                if page == 0:
                    components[1][1].disabled = False
                    components[1][0].disabled = False
                page += 1
                if page == len(pages)-1:
                    components[1][2].disabled = True
                    components[1][3].disabled = True
              await interaction.edit_origin(embed=pages[page], components=components)
```

In this part of code that button commands are working perfectly but when i use this select part(drop-down) it selects the particular thing but not updating the embed and disabling the buttons and even it stops the working of button.
Is there anyway to fix this problem. I couldn't understand what is the problem. Someone help me to solve this problem.
**Thank you for help in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a struggle i found that problem is with the select command.
I changed the `components[0][0].default=False` to `components[0][0].options[0].default=False` as i realized i didn't get the options. Then this works fine for me.
**Thank you  for the people who tried to solve this code for me**

Below is my code which works perfectly now (:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def select_and_buttons(self, ctx):
      embed1=discord.Embed(title="no:1")
      embed2=discord.Embed(title="no:2")
      embed3=discord.Embed(title="no:3")
      embed4=discord.Embed(title="no:4")
      embed5=discord.Embed(title="no:5")
      embed6=discord.Embed(title="no:6")
      embed7=discord.Embed(title="no:7")
      embed8=discord.Embed(title="no:8")
      embed9=discord.Embed(title="no:9")
      embed10=discord.Embed(title="no:10")
      pages = [embed1, embed2, embed3, embed4, embed5]
      page0 = [embed1, embed2, embed3, embed4, embed5]
      page1 = [embed6, embed7, embed8, embed9, embed10]
      total_pages=[page0,page1]
      page = 0
      category="Moderation"
      components = [
          [
              Select(
                  placeholder="Select something",
                  options=[
                      SelectOption(label='Moderation', value='Moderation', emoji='️',default=True),
                      SelectOption(label='Giveaway', value='Giveaway', emoji=''),
                      SelectOption(label='Games', value='Games', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Music', value='Music', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Fun', value='Fun', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Utils', value='Utils', emoji='️',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Tickets', value='Tickets', emoji='',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='Others', value='Others', emoji='✨',default=False),
                      SelectOption(label='All', value='All', emoji='✨',default=False)
                      ],min_values=1,
                max_values=1
              )
          ],
          [
              Button(emoji="⏮️",label=' ', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='move_to_first',disabled=True),
              Button(emoji="⬅️",label=' ', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='move_to_back',disabled=True),
              Button(emoji="➡️",label=' ', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='move_to_next'),
              Button(emoji="⏭️",label=' ', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='move_to_last')
          ]
      ]

      message = await ctx.send(embed=pages[page], components=components)

      while True:
          try:
              interaction = await self.bot.wait_for(
                  'interaction',
                  check=lambda inter: inter.message.id == message.id,
                  timeout=60
              )
          except asyncio.TimeoutError:
              for row in components:
                  row.disable_components()
              return await message.edit(content='Timed out!', components=components)



          if isinstance(interaction.component, Select):
            categories=["Moderation","Giveaway","Games","Music","Fun","Utils","Tickets","Others"]
            index_before = categories.index(category)
            index_now=categories.index(interaction.values[0])
            category=interaction.values[0]
            components[0][0].options[index_before].default=False
            components[0][0].options[index_now].default=True
            pages=page1
            page=0
            components[1][1].disabled = True
            components[1][0].disabled = True
            await interaction.edit_origin(embed=pages[page],components=components)


          # else:
          if isinstance(interaction.component, Button):
              if interaction.custom_id=="move_to_first": 
                if(page==len(pages)-1):
                  components[1][2].disabled = False
                  components[1][3].disabled = False
                page=0  
                components[1][1].disabled = True
                components[1][0].disabled = True

              if interaction.custom_id=="move_to_last": 
                if(page==0):
                  components[1][1].disabled = False
                  components[1][0].disabled = False
                page=len(pages)-1 
                components[1][2].disabled = True
                components[1][3].disabled = True  

              if interaction.custom_id == 'move_to_back':
                if page == len(pages)-1:
                    components[1][2].disabled = False
                    components[1][3].disabled = False
                page -= 1
                if page == 0:
                    components[1][1].disabled = True
                    components[1][0].disabled = True
              elif interaction.custom_id == 'move_to_next':
                if page == 0:
                    components[1][1].disabled = False
                    components[1][0].disabled = False
                page += 1
                if page == len(pages)-1:
                    components[1][2].disabled = True
                    components[1][3].disabled = True
              await interaction.edit_origin(embed=pages[page], components=components)
```